# Difference between Middleware, Gateway, and Service?

Tags: service, backend

Could anyone explain the general difference between those 3 terms?

If I want to make a small backend service that get data from other BE service and forward to frontend, what would it be called?

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon your architecture.
Middleware: Usually, middleware is something that sits between your Huge ODS or databases and you services. Middleware can be used for many things like speeding up data queries, caching, etc. Usually, middleware contains SQL Materialized VIEWS. Middleware can be used to filter only required data to a smaller database from huge ODS or database.

Gateway: Gateway is just a single entry point for clients to call API services.

Services: Services hold main logics and processing of data to be sent to clients via API.